# Can no longer open Chrome Apps from Windows 10 Startmenu

Tags: windows, windows-10, google-chrome, start-menu

As of today, I can no longer open Chrome Apps from the Windows 10 Startmenu.
This worked up until yesterday evening's shutdown of the computer.

[image: startmenu screenshot of apps]

I already tried restarting the machine. Also, the apps still work, I can open them just fine from Chrome directly (in a separate window as intended).

All other apps in the windows startmenu, eg Chrome itself, Games, Lightroom/Photoshop, also still work just fine to start from there.

I was wondering what could have caused this. I didn't really notice any significant updates to Chrome or Windows yesterday.

Comment: One idea would be to unpin them from the _Start Menu_ and repin them there, then check again to see if they are working again.

Comment: On a second thought, this issue could be bigger than it seems. I can clearly see the _GitHub Desktop_ Software Application in the _Apps and Features_ Pane, but _Windows_ _Search_ does not find it, nor can I find it inside the File System. How can they just disappear like that?

Comment: On a third thought, actually they do not disappear. The _GitHub Desktop_ Software Application resides in the `C:\Users\DOBRE\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\GitHubDesktop.exe` Folder. I still do not understand why _Windows_ cannot find it.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the shortcut properties? Is anything appearing in the event viewer when to try to access them?

Comment: Windows 10 v 1903 right ???

Answer (score 0):

Hello and thank you for your inputs!
Actually the hint towards properties by @Burgi got me on the right track again.

Some time ago I found a solution for the ever recurring "Google Chrome App Icons don't get displayed in Windows 10 Startmenu" 'bug'.
Thread: [How to get Chrome favicons to appear in Windows 10 start menu?](https://superuser.com/questions/1143974/how-to-get-chrome-favicons-to-appear-in-windows-10-start-menu)

- first solution usually helped, to update the manifest.xml
- but since last time it did not, i resorted to the second "easier" variant (also in the linked topic), by creating a copy of Chrome.exe, and had the app shortcut point to the new one.

Now, for some reason, the second solution and "Chrome2.exe" in general, stopped working. Surprising easy fix for this issue: delete and re-create.
Now all my shortcuts work again...
Still do not know why the exe copy stopped working though.